# How to put the application icon of the "Articles" sample in the application bar of the Oracle WebCenter Sites

Tags: java, oracle, webcenter-sites

Good Morning,

I'm following the documentation at the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/wemregisteringapp.htm

I have succeed in start the application. I can go at path: `http://localhost:9180/Articles-1.0/home.app` and use the application. However I want also to add the Articles Icon on the application bar like in this figure:

http://imageshack.com/a/img839/3513/rzz.gif

I follow all of the step-by-step guide at the first link but nothing appens in the application bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it out and I see the problem. For some reason it's appending the URL of the image to the base URL:`http://sites-server:8080/cs/http://articles-server:9080/articles-1.0/images/articles.png`

If you've installed the articles application on the same appserver as Sites, you can try changing the icon URL to: ../articles-1.0/images/articles.png

and the layout URL to: ../articles-1.0/layout.app

Or try copying the articles.png from your {deployed articles-1.0)/images and layout.jsp from your {deployed articles-1.0}/WEB-INF/jsp into the deployed Sites application somewhere, and change the URLs accordingly. E.g. if you place them both in {deployed Sites app}/articles/, then change the URLs to /articles/articles.png and /articles/layout.jsp (not .app!) respectively.

I'll raise a bug for the fact that it's appending the URLs to the Sites base URL.